# Where do files loaded (by a tool) from a remote location get stored?

Tags: networking

I have a tool that loads files and processes them. I simply pass in a file path or a URL and the tool figures out how to handle it. The files can be stored on local disk, a network drive, a remote server, etc.

When I specify a location and then press "Run", the tool starts doing its work.

If the location is a mapped drive on our local network, the first time I run it, the file needs to be transferred, but for subsequent runs I don't see any activity on the network.

This leads me to believe that it's being stored somewhere since it isn't fetching it multiple times, but where is it stored?

Comment: File Cache: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364218(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yes, and each program saves the files in its own temporary folder.